# How to schedule script through CRONJOB in LINUX

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a script which will parse my already existing file. I want to apply cronjob in it in which I want to give timings that after every minute my script should execute automatically.How can I do it in linux script?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your crontab:

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/script
```

Use the command `crontab -e` to edit your crontab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have added it in crontab.
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly            
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
* * * * *  /op/wrd/send_mail.sh             #my script path

Comment: is this corrct way?How do i execute my script now?

Comment: My answer was for your personal crontab, which you update using `crontab -e`, not the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301322/841108) and have a script running every minute thru a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry.

However, since you want to trigger some action when a file has changed, on Linux specifically, you could also use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities, and have something run when a particular file has been modified. Then use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)